# php pass variable into date string

Tags: php, string, date

How would it be possible to pass a variable into a date string?  I have the following variables:

```
$start_date = date('2014-01-01');
$end_date = date('2014-12-31');
```

But now I am adding it to a loop where the year (2014) will change each time through, and I have that new year assigned as:

```
$dateArr[0];
```

But when I try to do this it doesn't work:

```
$start_date = date('$dateArr[0]-01-01');
$end_date = date('$dateArr[0]-12-31');
```

How could I work this syntax to pass a variable into a date string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Variables are not interpolated in single quote strings. Use double quotes instead:

```
$start_date = date("$dateArr[0]-01-01");
$end_date = date("$dateArr[0]-12-31");
```

FYI, this is more straight forward using `DateTime()`:

```
$start_date = new DateTime("2014-01-01");
$end_date =  new DateTime("2014-12-31");
```

Then when it is time to increment to the next year just use the `modify()` method to add one year:

```
$start_date->modify('+1 year');
$end_date->modify('+1 year');
```

Comment: You've made someone very very happy, you got a "Woo Hoo" ;)